# Manipulate the output of select query

Tags: sql, distinct

I have requirements to retrieve the unique mobile number from database.
The issue is the number is not having a fixed format some starts with
`+CountryCode` or `00CountryCode` or without `+` and `country code`

So I want to manipulate them to have a single format using If.
But i don't want to change there value in the database I just want to change it 
in the query itself.

I don't know how to do this with `DISTINCT`

this is what i did so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT PhoneNumber
FROM User
where  (len(PhoneNumber) = 13 or len(PhoneNumber) = 10 or phoneNumber like '311%' or phoneNumber like '00311%' )
```

Comment: can you plse share some sample data as `text`??

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper what do you mean exactly

Comment: it means some dummy user data which can may helpful to understand problem and  figure out or improve your solution

Comment: Is this MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case when`. Here is the solution for **MySQL**

```
select distinct case when length(phone) = 10 then concat('00382', right(phone ,(length(phone)-1)))
                     when length(phone) = 13 then replace(phone, '+', '00')
                     when length(phone) = 12 then concat ('00', phone)
                     else phone
                end 
from myTable;
```

Here I assumed you will have phone numbers that are 10 digits long for exaple: 0123456789
I also assumed when the numbers have country code then the first digit is not displayed, for example : 00382123456789 (14 digits long).

So having that assumed I have done this:

- If number is long 10 digits (0123456789) add country code (00382) and
  remove first digit (0)
- If number is long 13 digits then treplace + with 00
- If number is long 12digits then add 00

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b231352c0443d45d5fdb8b256326991a)

And here is the solution for **SQLServer**:

```
select distinct case when len(phone) = 10 then concat('00382', right(phone ,(len(phone)-1)))
                     when len(phone) = 13 then replace(phone, '+', '00')
                     when len(phone) = 12 then concat ('00', phone)
                     else phone
                end 
from myTable;
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what i wanted just made some small adjustments . Now if I have two cases for len(13) how can i do it? like there are two different formats with 13 length

Comment: @rav feel free to message me here with the new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(PHONENUMER,10) FROM USER
```

Is this useful, i.e. get last 10 digits ?

Comment: it only retrieve last 10 digit, so what about country code ?

Comment: If I not miss understand ,As per Problem statement query `len(PhoneNumber) = 13` may state there may need country code.

Comment: if the country code id 311 and i get the last 10 digits i will get (1) from the country code which should be replaced by 0 , so this will give incorrect number